# My Spain Schengen visa was refused twice and appeals rejected

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, spain

I was refused for a Schengen visa in February 2018 for *justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.* I had an invitation letter from a sponsor company and all other documents were clear. I appealed and was refused.

I tried again in August and was refused again for the same reason. The company in Spain sent many emails to the Embassy to try to help me, but didn't get a  clear answer.

What should I do now? I appealed and was refused on the same day. I don't know what the Consulate has against me. I have to travel to check the company production lines and finish financial transactions. Can I ask the company to invite me via the police authority?

Comment: Did the company engage a lawyer to help with your application? If not, that would be an obvious next step.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the company (other visa carriers disappeared, exploiting employees, ...). Did you know well that company? Did you research in internet about such company? (not company website, but opinion and news stories about it). A company sending many email to the embassy and not phone call? Or just you overestimated the invitation letter: it is just a piece of paper: you still need all other documents that proof that you will leave the country.

Comment: thanks so much for your comment. i will do my best to re apply again and i will consult professionals. but when i should apply again? i want to apply again in a very short period of time

Comment: you can apply whenever, but if you don't approve your application the result will be the same. appealing in this situation is pointless.

Comment: See the suggested duplicate for advice on how to improve your visa application.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I ask the company to invite me via the police authority?

Your entry into the EU is not a basic human right. A visa is a privilege and not a right at least in your case. If you are getting your visas refused and appeals rejected you can not ask police or any form of law enforcement to help you. They will laugh it off. Unless your sponsor is a government organization a sponsor does not have any authority over the immigration officials in deciding visa applications.

Your applications are unable to satisfy the officers that you seek a non immigrant entry and subsequently intend to leave after your trip. As has already been stated in the comments, you need professional assistance with this. Consult an immigration solicitor.

> I have to travel to check the company production lines and finish financial transactions

They don't care a dime about that. If you don't satisfy the ECO you are not going there, that company can do whatever.

Sorry if it sounds harsh, but sugar coating won't help you. Don't feel entitled to receive that visa, **seek assistance from a solicitor**.

Comment: thanks so much for your comment. i will do my best to re apply again and i will consult professionals. but when i should apply again? i want to apply again in a very short period of time

Comment: Those professionals will know much better. Any random advice from an internet forum wont help much after a series of refusals. We don't even know what your refusal letter says